# Rebuilt table and added Identity in an upgrade tool, but the script isn't repeatable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been tasked with fixing an SQL script that takes a nullable un-indexed ID column and makes sure every row has an ID. Then it creates a duplicate table, with with the ID column an an Identity & PK and uses a SWITCH TO command to move the data over before dropping the old one and renaming the new one. At the moment, the nulls are replaced using the while loop below, but when the table's already been updated it throws the following error:

> Cannot update identity column 'myID'

My assumption is that it's not even trying to go into the loop, but SQL Server's recognised that there's an update on what's now an identity field and has thrown a hissy-fit. This is part of a batch of upgrade scripts, so will be run regularly, but obviously we want to avoid this error being thrown.

Once the column becomes an identity column we won't need to change the values. Can the error be suppressed, or are there other solutions I should consider?

```
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myID IS null)
BEGIN
    UPDATE myTable 
    SET myID=(SELECT MAX(myID)+1 FROM myTable) 
    FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM myTable WHERE myID IS NULL) AS n 
    WHERE n.myVarChar = myTable.myVarChar -- This is unique, but we don't use text fields as IDs
END
GO
```

Thanks!

Comment: SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON myTable

Answer (score 0):

You should add check:

```
IF columnproperty(object_id('mytable'),'myId','IsIdentity') = 0
BEGIN
  WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myID IS null)
  BEGIN
    UPDATE myTable 
    SET myID=(SELECT MAX(myID)+1 FROM myTable) 
    FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM myTable WHERE myID IS NULL) AS n 
    WHERE n.myVarChar = myTable.myVarChar;
  END
END
```

If column `myID` has identity property you could skip execution of your code.

Comment: The problem with IDENTITY_INSERT ON is it's intended for updates (because you can't use update on an identity column. And the clause on the WHILE effectively does the same thing as your IF statement, Nothing in there is going to be null while it's an identity column. :/

Comment: @AMGitsKriss You don't need to `UPDATE` when your column has set `IDENTITY` property. Adding check before your code will ensure that after you run your script you won't be trying to update unecessary tables.

Comment: That's part of my issue. The first time this script is run it works, because it's not an identity column at that point. But because it's part of a "bring to latest version" utility, it's going to be executed repeatedly.